# No events in the Today scope on Ubuntu Phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, scopes

My BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition has access to my Google account, but none of my Google calender items is shown as part of the Events section of the Today scope.

Why is there no events in the Today scope on my Ubuntu Phone?

How to populate the Events section of the Today scope? What are the sources for the Events section?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/syncevolution/+bug/1438662

Basically, even with google account connected, the calendar app is not able to sync with google due to an issue with syncevolution. Events on the Today scope behave the same way.
A fix has been provided (it has been reported as working for vivid version) and is supposed to land via hot-fix the next week for BQ phones.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will wait for the 15.04 OTA update and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This bug might be already corrected, since I was able to sync manually the calendar (the app made by ubuntu core developpers which works with the scope) whit my google calendar. It was finally done last night, hope it helps.